# (nested) user controls within a mvp pattern causing sporadic problems

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, user-controls, mvp

I have a serious problem with nested user controls (UCs) in WinForms while trying to implement the mvp pattern (passive view). The project consists of one model (designed as a singleton) and a set of different presenters with corresponding view interfaces. To avoid one huge view interface and therefore an overloaded main UI, I decided to make use of a set of different UCs. Each UC has one view interface and one presenter that can access the model. But there are nested UCs: meaning that one specialised UC implements sort of a basic UC. The main UI just represents a container for all those UCs. So far, so good (if not, please ask)?!

There are two problems that I am facing now (but I guess both are of the same origin):

1. From time to time it is not possible anymore to load the UCs and test them within the Visual Studio 2008 User Control Test Container. The error message just says that a project with an output type of class library cannot be started directly etc. I can "handle" that by unloading all UC projects and reloading them afterwards. (I guess the references to all mvp components and other UCs are then updated).
2. Assuming that the implementation of my mvp pattern is okay and all those UCs are testable within the VS Test Container at a certain time - there is the biggest problem still left: I am not able to add any UC (even the basic and unnested ones) to a simple Form (UI).

Could it be that my basic UC causes all these Problems?! It consists of two simple ComboBoxes and implements a basic presenter and basic view interface. Whenever I add this UC to a different UC the VS designer adds two references to the public getter methods of the UC as resources. I then manually remove those resources from the resx-file and commend the corresponding lines in the designer file.

Comment: I could fix the last "bug" concerning my Basic UC by hiding special getters with the attribute Hidden of the DesignerSerializationVisibility class thx to that post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470538 But the main problem still exists. I cannot add my UC to a form in a proper way. Sometimes I can add one of the many UCs, but there are again errors with the other UCs. So I really guess that it is a problem  concerning the libraries of the UCs that am I referencing to. Any Ideas, hints. I would really appreciate it. thx

Comment: There is also an error concerning my model class (designed as a singleton). Every Presenter accesses an method of that singleton class which returns a certain object. From time to time a warning occurs saying that Object[A] of that class is not compatible to Object[B] of the same class. So again a lib bug?

Answer (score 0):

For the second one: You should use `DesingMode` property of the `Component` class (which `UserControl` derives) in your code. Be aware, there is a bug with this property not having correct value with nested user controls.
This can help you, I think: [When your WinForms UserControl drives you nuts](http://weblogs.asp.net/rweigelt/archive/2003/09/03/26262.aspx)